# How to find a yum repository

Tags: linux, repository

Hi I'm trying to find a repository on the web for oddjob-mkhomedir.

I'm then going to try and add it to linux so I can install the library with these instructions

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Managing_Yum_Repositories.html

Can someone help me to find this repository? I've been looking for almost 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

On the machines that I manage, this package was installed from the Red Hat Satellite repositories.  You will need a Red Hat Satellite subscription in order to access these particular repositories.

Comment: is there any way to use these http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/oddjob-mkhomedir

Answer (score 1):

`oddjob-mkhomedir` should be in the base channel or in the `yum` repo on the RHEL6 install DVD.

Is it not? If not (or if you don't have a subscription anymore) you can try to download the centos version and install that.

Comment: yes it is in rhel6 DVD : Packages/oddjob-mkhomedir-0.30-5.el6.*

Comment: Sorry, I was using AMI which wasn't part of their distro.